# Tone.js Library Import Tone in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, tone.js

I'm using tone.js library version ("tone": "**^14.7.34**") with vue.js

**Vue code:**

`import Tone from "tone"`

also tried

`import { Tone } from "tone"`

**Warning** in log:
"export 'default' (imported as 'Tone') was not found in 'tone'

*Does anyone know how I can import Tone object from tone.js library?*

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Installation)?

Comment: `Import * as Tone from 'tone'` or `import { submodule } from 'tone'` works for me in Vue.